# Как запарсить необычную html страничку без div и class

Tags: python, парсер, lxml

Помогите разобраться, как запарсить страничку по ссылке:
https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/bonds/securities?marketprice_board=1
Делаю по методу
`soup = bs(response, 'lxml')`
мне выдает вообще всю таблицу из которой я не понимаю, как мне взять всего лишь нужный тикер **RU000A107C34** и данные по нему...хэлп!

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Что вы видете в браузере и что вы скачали (response), не одно и тоже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

response = requests.get('https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/bonds/securities?marketprice_board=1')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "xml")
tt = soup.find(ISIN='RU000A107C34').attrs
print(tt)

# "{'SECID': 'RU000A107C34', 'BOARDID': 'TQCB', 'SHORTNAME': 'АйДиКоле06', 'PREVWAPRICE': '99.92', 'YIELDATPREVWAPRICE': '19.61', 'COUPONVALUE': '14.79', 'NEXTCOUPON': '2024-04-05', 'ACCRUEDINT': '6.9', 'PREVPRICE': '99.96', 'LOTSIZE': '1', 'FACEVALUE': '1000', 'BOARDNAME': 'Т+: Облигации - безадрес.', 'STATUS': 'A', 'MATDATE': '2026-11-21', 'DECIMALS': '2', 'COUPONPERIOD': '30', 'ISSUESIZE': '2500000', 'PREVLEGALCLOSEPRICE': '99.96', 'PREVDATE': '2024-03-18', 'SECNAME': 'АйДи Коллект 06', 'REMARKS': '', 'MARKETCODE': 'FNDT', 'INSTRID': 'EICB', 'SECTORID': '', 'MINSTEP': '0.01', 'FACEUNIT': 'SUR', 'BUYBACKPRICE': '', 'BUYBACKDATE': '0000-00-00', 'ISIN': 'RU000A107C34', 'LATNAME': 'ID Collect 06', 'REGNUMBER': '4B02-04-00597-R', 'CURRENCYID': 'SUR', 'ISSUESIZEPLACED': '2374054', 'LISTLEVEL': '3', 'SECTYPE': '8', 'COUPONPERCENT': '18.000', 'OFFERDATE': '', 'SETTLEDATE': '2024-03-20', 'LOTVALUE': '1000', 'FACEVALUEONSETTLEDATE': '1000'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Мне кажется тут проще распарсить полученный `xml` с помощью регулярных выражений.
Это пример. поправите под свои нужды.
P.S Я не питонист, за код не обессудьте :)

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import requests
import re

#Читаем с сайта
URL = "https://iss.moex.com/iss/engines/stock/markets/bonds/securities?marketprice_board=1"
response = requests.get(URL)
#Парсим
result = re.findall(r'<row SECID="RU000A107C34" BOARDID="(.*?)" SHORTNAME="(.*?)" PREVWAPRICE="(.*?)" YIELDATPREVWAPRICE="(.*?)" COUPONVALUE="(.*?)" NEXTCOUPON="(.*?)" ACCRUEDINT="(.*?)" PREVPRICE="(.*?)" LOTSIZE="(.*?)" FACEVALUE="(.*?)" BOARDNAME="(.*?)" STATUS="(.*?)" MATDATE="(.*?)" DECIMALS="(.*?)" COUPONPERIOD
="(.*?)" ISSUESIZE="(.*?)" PREVLEGALCLOSEPRICE="(.*?)" PREVDATE="(.*?)" SECNAME="(.*?)" REMARKS="(.*?)" MARKETCODE="(.*?)" INSTRID="(.*?)" SECTORID="(.*?)" MINSTEP="(.*?)" FACEUNIT="(.*?)" BUYBACKPRICE="(.*?)" BUYBACKDATE="(.*?)" ISIN="(.*?)" LATNAME="(.*?)" REGNUMBER="(.*?)" CURRENCYID="(.*?)" ISSUESIZEPLACED="(.*?
)" LISTLEVEL="(.*?)" SECTYPE="(.*?)" COUPONPERCENT="(.*?)" OFFERDATE="(.*?)" SETTLEDATE="(.*?)" LOTVALUE="(.*?)" FACEVALUEONSETTLEDATE="(.*?)" \/>',data)

print(result)
```

Результат

> [('TQCB', 'АйДиКоле06', '99.92', '19.61', '14.79', '2024-04-05', '6.9', '99.96', '1', '1000', 'Т+: Облигации - безадрес.', 'A', '2026-11-21', '2', '30', '2500000', '99.96', '2024-03-18', 'АйДи Коллект 06', '', 'FNDT', 'EICB', '', '0.01', 'SUR', '', '0000-00-00', 'RU000A107C34', 'ID Collect 06', '4B02-04-00597-R', 'SUR', '2374054', '3', '8', '18.000', '', '2024-03-20', '1000', '1000')]
> P.S Я не питонист, за код не обессудьте